# Update git local branch clone with tortoise git

Tags: git, git-commit, tortoisegit, git-clone

Architecture:

- git repo A is on PC A with no internet
- git repo C is a duplicate of gitA, created via Git Clone and is on hdd
- git repo B is a duplicate of gitC, created via Git Clone and is on pcB

Scenario:

- gitA is a shared folder used between team members
- I work on gitB on pcB
- I need to update files from gitB -> gitC -> gitA
- Then from gitA -> gitC -> gitB after resolving conflict with members in gitA

How can I achieve the above scenario?

Comment: Who is remote of who in this scenario? Tell me if I got this OK, and please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61615598/edit) your question to express it better. HDD is clone of A, so A is remote of HDD. B is remote of HDD? A has no remote set.

Comment: @DaemonPainter i've updated the question. sorry for the confusion

Comment: What are B and C? Clones of the whole repository? What is a "local clone"? A clone on the same PC?

Comment: Let me make an example for you. I once had a folder I wanted to version, let's call it `git A`. I was working on a machine without internet connection, so I cloned `git A` into a "backup" folder on a USB drive. Let's call this "backup" `git usB`. Now A don't have a remote, and usB has A as remote. A pushes to nobody, B pulls from A. I work in A, so I make new commits in A. The in B I `git pull` from A. I hope this helps you removing some confusion, I cannot understand how is your architecture.

Comment: @DaemonPainter I've updated the question to provide more details. Although, you've actually provided the solution for gitB -> gitC. I did not know that both gits are still linked and can be pulled easily as the only info given by tortoise is Remote: origin. does it mean that I can also just call pull on gitA to fulfil the B -> C -> A scenario and pull on gitC and gitB to fulfil the A -> C -> B scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You are working in a triangular-y fashion.

The [blessed repo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrator_workflow) is A and is <strike>shared</strike> on a machine without internet connection. You work on B.
<strike>A is origin of B, and thus you push/pull to A from B. This can be achieve from your working repo using Tortoise context menu, shouldn't be a big deal.</strike>

C is a backup of A, on a machine that has internet connection. Thus, C is actually the *blessed repo* and B is child of C. B should be able to push/pull to C directly. <strike>B and C are not in a parent/child relation, but are siblings. You may say that C is a repository on PC C that your colleague Carlo is working on.</strike>

You would like to push to C from B. To do so, the remote of B should be set to C, not A.
Then you'd like to push to A from C. Rephrasing, you want to push changes to your colleage Carlo, then have Carlo publish anything to the *blessed repository* A. Only thing here is that Carlo doesn't exists.

What I would suggest you is to make C a mirror copy of A. <strike>avoid pushing to C</strike>. <strike>C is a backup of A, thus keep going and `git fetch` in C from A</strike>. B is a working copy, will push to <strike>A</strike>C directly and pull from <strike>A</strike>C directly. <strike>*"Hey, but any changes we made to solve conflicts in A will be in B as well, I don't want that!"* No, you want that, because sooner or later those changes will enter in B.</strike>

Your backup C should be a `git clone --mirror` see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies `--bare`.
>   Compared to `--bare`, `--mirror` not only *maps local branches of the*
>   *source to local branches of the target*, it maps all refs (including
>   remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec
>   configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a `git remote update`
>   in the target repository.

Use `git remote update` to push your changes from C to A whenever you are able to connect the USB stick (?) to A that has no internet connection.

Comment: the suggested method only works if there is a "link" between A and B but unfortunately in my case, there is no direct connection between A and B thus there is a need of C. I updated the question slightly to perhaps ease some confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the confusion. all I can say is, this architecture is born from covid19. gitA is a shared repo in the office that connects only to the office server, gitB is the one I work on at home with no internet, gitC is for transferring between A and B.